# Function over a list that depends on the index

Tags: list-manipulation, index

Suppose I have a list

```
{a, b, c, d}
```

**I want to operate on this list with a function which depends on the index of the element, e.g. I want to add the index number to each element to get**

```
{a+1, b+2, c+3, d+4}
```

what would be the best way to do this?

I have seen some possible approaches but was wondering what the 'canonical' way would be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html):

```
MapIndexed[#2[[1]] + # &, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> {1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c, 4 + d}

Also

```
Range[Length @ #] + # & @ {a,b,c,d}
```

> {1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c, 4 + d}

Answer (score 5):

A couple more options --

```
lst = {a, b, c, d};

Table[lst[[n]] + n, {n, Length[lst]}]
```

> {1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c, 4 + d}

```
lst + Range[Length[lst]]
```

> {1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c, 4 + d}

Answer (score 2):

Four more possibilities:

```
list = {a, b, c, d};

Array[{list[[#]] + #} &, Length @ list]
```

{{1 + a}, {2 + b}, {3 + c}, {4 + d}}

```
Module[{i = 1}, # + i++ &] /@ list
```

{1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c, 4 + d}

```
ReplacePart[i_ :> list[[i]] + i] @ list
```

{1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c, 4 + d}

```
Module[{i = 1}, Replace[list, x_ :> x + i++, {1}]]
```

{1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c, 4 + d}

`Replace` can be useful if we want to impose a `Condition`:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, Missing[], 4};

Module[{i = 1}, Replace[list, x_Integer :> x + i++, {1}]]
```

{2, 4, 6, Missing[], 8}